# Alternatives for using IN in mysql queries for retrieving rows

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

In order to retrieve rows  from a table in a mysql database, where the column id is equal to 2, 4, 6, 8,....., can someone suggest alternative ways in which these values can be searched for without using IN. I guess we can use OR but is there ant other way?

Comment: Why would you not want to use `IN`?

Comment: I am just looking for alternatives! And to see if there are any pros and cons between the different ways.

Comment: Ah, so you want to get rows with even numbers only. I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways. Some proposals:

1. Simply: `SELECT ... WHERE mod(id, 2) = 0`
   In some SQL implementations you can use modulo operator `%` instead of `mod()`.
2. Conditional: `SELECT CASE mod(id, 2) WHEN 0 THEN ... ELSE ...`
   [Explanation of SELECT...CASE statement.](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15633)
   [Good example.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Select-Query/Countallemployeesbyevenoddemployeeid.htm)
3. Regular expression: `SELECT ... WHERE id LIKE '%[02468]'`
   It returns records with only these id, which are ending with 0, 2, 4, 6 or 8. Even ones.